# Why do I need 125 reputation to downvote but only 15 to upvote?

Tags: support, voting, privileges

I've been looking at the reputation tab recently and I noticed that to upvote, you need 15 reputation, but to downvote, you need 125 reputation. Why do you need so much more reputation to downvote than to upvote?

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178529

Comment: And by the way, you may be interested in this help center page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: My view is surely colored by my own rep and rep history, but from where I'm standing, the difference between 15 and 125 rep is large only in a relative sense.  110 rep isn't that much.

Comment: Is/should there be an upper cap (daily/weekly/monthly/)on down votes ?

Comment: @qqqqq there is a daily vote limit of 30 (up and down) with an additional 10 for questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Why have voters deleted the answers? Is it appropriate to vote to delete any answer that we disagree with, even if accepted?

Comment: @user000001 Not a single one of the deleted answers make any kind of sense.

Answer (score 75):

Downvoting indirectly moderates users to an extent, and this power should not be given lightly.

There are, today, 1.7 million accounts which can upvote posts, and only 580,000 accounts which can *just* downvote today (reference - [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/924799)).

Because downvotes do directly impact a user's ability to post questions or answers - Stack Overflow moreso than any other site on the network - allowing 1.7 million people to suddenly participate in downvoting others would be a significant problem, since there's no guarantee that those downvotes wouldn't *just* be out of spite.

Worse yet, it doesn't take much in the way of effort to get to 15+ reputation, so mass downvotes could be orchestrated in a more efficient and coordinated way.

It's too much power to give someone who barely understands its long-term impact.

Comment: "since there's no guarantee that those downvotes wouldn't just be out of spite." note that anonymous users, don't have this problem.

Comment: @Braiam:  Anonymous users and anonymous posts are anymore treated like red-headed stepchildren.  They exist but the amount of concern I as an average Metahound give them is a rounding error on even the most sympathetic of days.

Comment: @Matoko Is there any significance of 125 rep? Why not 100 or 200, for example?

Comment: @dwirony yes. 100 is the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). Requiring 125 reputations means users who are part of one community on the SE network must at least put in some effort to participate in another community before downvoting there.

Comment: I have been downvoted because my answer is out of date  (1 years later).  This can occur if say the post is about a bug in a service and that bug was fixed.  My post now looks like it is wrong.  I don't see a way to mark a question or answer as out of date. That would help prevent some unnecessary downvotes and loss of reputation.

Comment: @MarkD:  The vote was likely appropriate.  Up or downvotes represent usefulness or lack thereof, respectively.  Your answer was useful when it was posted to it was worth upvoting.  Your answer is not useful now, so it's a likely candidate to be downvoted.  You could always add a disclaimer that this is how it was in an older version of whichever software/technology you were using, but outside of that, I wouldn't deride others for using the system to indicate the true value/usefulness of content.

Comment: @makato, good advice and that is what I do now - I add a comment.  I guess there is some confusion in me between the value of my questions (that can be downvoted to -1) and my reputation. The other side is the ranking of usefulness and I agree with your point.  Take .net  4.6.0 and 4.6.1.  If my answer pointed out an issue in 4.6.0, then that remains valuable for anyone using 4.6.0.  It could be downvoted because 4.6.1 fixed the issue though.  As your suggestion, I can clarify that in an update.  I'm good with your answer (and I won't downvote it :-) )

Comment: Upvoting directly moderates a user, too.

Comment: One of the few times I've downvoted one of your posts. I cannot understand why would we trust someone who doesn't know the site to say "this is useful" but not to say "this is not useful". People upvote crap and downvote excellent answers. BTW, massive upvotes/downvotes are dealt with pretty quickly, so I don't understand that point either.

Answer (score 31):

An upvote signifies that a post was useful.  A downvote is more complicated.  It can signal deviation from "community standards".  It can also indicate that a post has a flaw.

Anyone can find something useful, and we want to encourage new folks to become part of the community.  But, before you can start criticizing other folks' posts, you really need to prove that you know a little about those standards and that you've spent a little time on the site.

It doesn't take long to earn 125 rep if you know a little about what you are talking about.  During that time, you learn what's acceptable and what's not just by taking part in the community discussion.  Until you do, you really shouldn't be downvoting other SO members.

Consider the real world.  If you work on a team, and you have, say, one year experience.  If you show your code to a senior team member and to a team member who joined last month (right out of school).  You'll accept compliments from the new team member, but you would be very doubtful of any negative feedback from someone with a three-month old bachelor's degree.  On the other hand, when you get criticism from that senior team member, you're likely to respond with: "thanks, that was a great catch".

Comment: If you're doubtful about validity of someone's feedback, what does it matter whether said feedback is positive or negative?

Comment: @DanMašek: Going back to the junior and senior members of the team I work on.  A junior member may be assigned a task, find some of your code, use it (either directly, or after modification) and then, the next day say in a stand up "I was able to get this done faster than I thought because of Flydog's code" - that's an upvote.  But, if the same member finds some code that's well documented and used in several places in the project, comments that it's not good because, I don't know, it's too abstract - well, then I may not think his/her comments are a valid downvote.